# Gunicorn + eventlet use redis connection in SIGTERM signal handler

Tags: python, gunicorn, eventlet

I'm facing an issue related to using an active I/O connection in the SigTerm handler using gunicorn eventlet server.

server.py

```
def exit_with_grace(*args):
    conn = get_redis_connection()
    conn.set('exited_gracefully', True)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_with_grace)
```

I also tried to fire up the celery task (using amqp broker) but all my ideas failed. When I start server in debug mode using `python server.py` it works perfectly.  Gunicorn+ eventlet does not allow to connect to redis in sigterm handler, resulting with an following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/handlers/socketio/redis_context_backend.py", line 256, in publish_pattern
    return conn.publish(pattern, serialized)
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3098, in publish
    return self.execute_command('PUBLISH', channel, message)
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 898, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1192, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 559, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 603, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 250, in connect
    self._trampoline(fd, write=True)
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 210, in _trampoline
    mark_as_closed=self._mark_as_closed)
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 142, in trampoline
    assert hub.greenlet is not current, 'do not call blocking functions from the mainloop'
```

Gunicorn command:

`gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 server:ws --reload -b localhost:5001`